# Background-image body slider - как сделать плавнее?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, background

Нужен аля слайдер фоновых изображений страницы (body).
Ничего готового не нашёл, написал простенькую заготовку:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Background Slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sliderBackgroundBody()
{
    window.currBg = window.currBg + 1;
    if (!window.currBg || window.currBg > 4) window.currBg = 1;
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(bg' + window.currBg + '.jpg)');
    setTimeout(sliderBackgroundBody, 3000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    sliderBackgroundBody();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать смену фона более плавной?

p.s.: если знаете готовое решение тыкните носом в ссылку плиз ))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xdUBZ/1/

Comment: Спасибо за решение на основе CSS3, но плавности смены bacground-image не добавило же) На background-color да, плавнее, а вот на bacground-image резкая смена одной картинки на другую.

Comment: К тому же примеру добавьте http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опасити body по хрду не меняется. Сделал вам так.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Background Slider</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function sliderBackgroundBody() {
      window.currBg = window.currBg + 1;
      if (!window.currBg || window.currBg > 4) window.currBg = 1;
      $('#body').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-640-480-' + window.currBg + '.jpg)').fadeIn(500);
      });
      setTimeout(sliderBackgroundBody, 3000);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      sliderBackgroundBody();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="body"></div>
</body>

</html>
```